# UITableView doesn't reload data after HTTP request

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to implement a search function in my application where after the user taps search on the keyboard an `HTTP` request will be sent to the API and the data returned will be displayed in my `UITableView`. However, it's not working and I think it because the request is running in a separate thread. I've tried a bunch of different solutions but none seem to work. Below is my code. Thanks for the help!

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    //get string from searchBar textfield
    NSString* searched = self.searchBar.text;

    //format the API call to search for the "searched" item (%@ after 'search/')
    NSString* formattedURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/%@?results=0:100&fields=item_name,nf_total_fat,nf_protein,nf_total_carbohydrate&appId=f35a80a7&appKey=9263d4b1c216becb04681b1cd04d1815",searched];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:formattedURL] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            NSDictionary* foodsFoundDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

            //array holds an array of all the foods found from the API call
            NSArray* array;
            array = [foodsFoundDict valueForKey:@"hits"];

            //since the info needed is inside the dictionary @"fields" of each array element, loop through array and add each dictionary to the global searchedFoodsArray
            for(NSDictionary* dict in array){
                [self.searchedFoodsArray addObject:dict[@"fields"]];
            }
        }]resume];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    });

}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that you do get the response from the server? I mean response is not nil, right?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, that `for` loop can be eliminated, reduced to simply `[self.searchedFoodsArray addObjectsFromArray:[array valueForKey:@"fields"]];`

Comment: @JsW yea response is not nil, the table does get populated but only after i click "cancel" on the search bar

Comment: You should do `[self.tableView reloadData];` after the ` for(NSDictionary* dict in array)` loop inside the block. And maybe also need to call dispatch_async in main queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that you're reloadData'ing the tableView outside of the completion block of the URL request.  In addition, I'd take a second look at where you're putting tasks on the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are wrapping main queue grabbing around the background process (NSURLSession call). NSURLSession is actually running in background. So you need to have the main queue GCD inside the NSURLSession block. For example:

```
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:formattedURL] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    // your code updating tableview datasource.

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                   [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

    }]resume];
```

Comment: FYI, he should move the population of `searchedFoodsArray` to this block dispatched to the main queue, too.

Comment: okay i moved the dispatch_async into the dataTaskWithURL block and put everything originally in the dataTaskWithURL block into the dispatch_async block. It kind of works but the table doesn't get populated until after I click "cancel" on the search bar. Is there some way i can populate the table right after i hit "search" on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

***Simply Add to your closure:***

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

If you want your search Results to update in a reactive manner. create a seperate array for Search Result and update your table view to use that array by checking `self.searchBar.isActive`